# Forward to local address when in local network?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to set up my apache2 config so that a user is redirected from the public to the local IP of a website if he is in this local network. Basically, if someone is visiting the website of my raspberry pi (which is at my home) while being at my home, he should be redirected to the local IP.
I want to do this with mod_rewrite, or is there an other, better way?

Comment: Do you have any DHCP server in LAN?

Comment: You can bind to local address space, like 192.168.0.x

Answer (score 1):

On the apache alternative if you want to use mod_rewrite, it would go something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 192\.168\.1 
RewriteRule .* http://your.local.hostname/ [R=301,L]
```

Assuming your local network segment is 192.168.1.0/24. But I guess you get the idea.

This site has nice examples that could be helpful: http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/rewrite/

Comment: I get the idea, yes, but `%{REMOTE_HOST}` is always empty; any advice?

Comment: What about %{REMOTE_ADDR}? I believe to have REMOTE_HOST you need HostNameLookups and that wouldn't be good for performance...

Comment: That returns the public address when I access it via the Internet and returns the local address if I access the server via the local network :/